# Match text between characters (avoid nesting)

Tags: java, regex

Given:

```
"abc{defghij{kl}mnopqrst}uvwxyz{aaaaaaaaaa}"
```

I want to match the text between the characters `{` and the last `}` excluding nesting - i.e. the texts `{defghij{kl}mnopqrst}` and `{aaaaaaaaaa}`.

Without the nested `{kl}`, the regex expression `\{[^{}]*\}` works just fine. But not with the nested `{kl}`.

Is there a way to do this? If not possible, can I say "match text between { and } where the size of the enclosed text is at least, e.g. 3, characters so that the nested {kl} which contains two characters is not matched? (I'm assuming one level nesting)

Editor: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Thanks,

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Java doesn't support the sort of recursing you'd like, unfortunately (in PCRE you could `{(?:(?R)|[^{}])+}`)

Comment: If you are sure that nested levels wouldn't go more than one then you can safely use this `{(?:{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+)*}`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/N13a2K/1

Comment: @revo that doesn't work in Java.

Comment: It works ([see it here](https://ideone.com/dF0mQO)). It just needs a few proper escaping in Java.

Comment: Thanks! Please post it as an answer so that I close it as answered.

Comment: My pleasure but are you sure that nested levels will not go more than that?

Comment: In my case, yes. I have just one level nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your problem since nesting levels will not reach two, it is possible to solve it with a readable, short regex and that would be:

```
\{(?:\{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+)*}
```

*In Java you have to escape opening braces, as I did.*

Above regex matches an opening brace then looks for either something other than `{` and `}` characters (i.e. `[^{}]+`) or something enclosed in braces `{[^{}]*}` and repeats this pattern as much as possible then expects to match a closing brace.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/N13a2K/1/)